# LLVM check if array allocation has dynamic size or constant size

Tags: llvm

I want to check if an stack allocation of an array has a constant size or a dynamic size (calculated at runtime). For example

```
int myInt;
scanf("%d", &myInt);
int buffer[myInt]; //dynamic sized array
```

The dynamic sized array gets converted to llvm IR like this:

```
%myInt = alloca i32, align 4
%saved_stack = alloca i8*
%call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @__isoc99_scanf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32* %myInt)
%0 = load i32, i32* %myInt, align 4
%1 = zext i32 %0 to i64
%2 = call i8* @llvm.stacksave()
store i8* %2, i8** %saved_stack
%vla = alloca i32, i64 %1, align 16 //allocation
%3 = load i8*, i8** %saved_stack
call void @llvm.stackrestore(i8* %3)
```

A constant sized array:

```
int buffer2[123];
```

LLVM IR:

```
%buffer2 = alloca [123 x i32], align 16
```

How can I identify if an alloca instruction allocates a dynamically sized array or a constant sized array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `class AllocaInst` in "include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h". It contains a method that returns the size of allocated array

```
  /// Get the number of elements allocated. For a simple allocation of a single
  /// element, this will return a constant 1 value.
  const Value *getArraySize() const { return getOperand(0); }
```

Once you have the `Value *` for the size of the array, you should be able to analyze if that is a constant or not, by using `dyn_cast<ConstantInt>`. (grep for this expression. It is widely used in the code).